# How to edit with imagemagick with tiling window manager?

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

In my mostly default `xmonad` configuration, editing images is almost impossible because all tool windows (like crop or filetype selection) are spawned too small and at random places and are difficult to navigate.

On top of that, if the application doesn't take full screen and is resized or moved, I see image leftovers in the background which should be blank (I have no wallpaper).

Who's to fault? The application or the tiling manager?

Is there a principled way to deal with this problem?

Comment: "_I see image leftovers in the background which should be blank (I have no wallpaper)._" - have you tried using a "_black image_" as the wallpaper?

Comment: I'd probably suggest _not_ using a tiling window manager... can you share a screenshot that demonstrates the issue?